# Email option not showing up on Sharepoint site when setting up data driven subscriptions

Tags: email, sharepoint, reporting-services, subscriptions, data-driven

I'm trying to create a data driven subscription on Sharepoint site and I want use Delivery type as Email. But I don't see that option there. Can someone please help? Do I need to enable any option or configure email somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Email settings for the Reporting Services application in Sharepoint?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231673.aspx